# Pass data to custom component in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a custom component with a selector 
how do i pass data to it in angular 4 to show data in its template. like

```
<my-component data="shirts"></my-component>
```

And in my-component template

```
<h5>{{data.size}}</h5>
```

Not sure how to pass data down from parent to child component in angular 4.

Comment: Are you asking us to write you a tutorial? Or do you have code that is giving you a problem?

Comment: You should apply the [@Input() decorator](https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/components/app_structure/passing_data_into_components.html) to the component member.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If "data" variable it's an @Input() property, "data" should be between brackets to allow data binding.

```
<my-component [data]="shirts"></my-component>
```

You need to have this in your component:

```
@Input() data;
```

Don't forget to import "Input" from @angular/core